# Haskell Syntax with functions, specifically findMin function

Tags: function, haskell, syntax

I'm struggling with the syntax with Haskell. It's very simple, but i'm stuck.

I'm trying to write a findMin function that takes a list and finds the minimum. Here's my code, I have tried so many syntactical things that I'm up for any help I can get.

```
findMin [] = [0]
findMin list = if any < head list then findMin(tail) else take 1
```

And i get all sorts of type errors. What is going wrong??

(if it helps at all i have a background in object oriented programming)

Comment: What is `any`? Isn't that a function? Comparing against a function doesn't make much sense. Also, what are the errors?

Comment: And what's the `take 1` at the end meant to do? That will cause a type error since you're only partially applying `take`. I'd like to help, but I don't want to just write the function for you. You're going to need to narrow your question down, as there's a few things wrong with this code.

Comment: I saw that "any" was something you could use to mean any other element in the list.

Comment: I also saw that take 1 the tutorial i was reading as well. It was supposed to return the first element at the beginning of the list. I could write that a different way, that was just one of the things i tried.

Comment: No. Been awhile since I've written Haskell, but iirc, `any` is a function that takes a predicate and a list, and returns whether or not the predicate was true for any of the elements.

Comment: And `take 1` does do that, but you need to give it a list to take the first element of.

Comment: Using destructuring syntax would make this a lot cleaner.

Comment: Okay so if I understand what I'm doing wrong now, this is what I changed my function to:

Comment: `findMin list = if any (< head list) list then findMin(tail) else take 1 list` and this is the error i'm getting now: 

haskell1.hs:14:1: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[a1]’ with ‘[a] -> [a]’
      Expected type: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a1]
        Actual type: [a1] -> [a1]
    • Relevant bindings include
        findMin :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a1] (bound at haskell1.hs:14:1)

Comment: Never mind. I just needed to give tail a list. Thank you for helping me through learning simple syntax.

Comment: Edit your original post rather than posting code in the comments (formatting is not supported in comments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you've got things figured out in the comments but I'll add some things here hopefully to help. I also feel like I should quickly mention that Haskell already has a [`minimum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:minimum) function just in case anyone stumbles upon this who isn't just trying to learn the language and actually needs the function for something.

First of all let's talk about types. I would normally expect a `findMin` style of function to return the minimum value rather than that value inside a list so the type will be:
`findMin :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a`

The things before `=>` add context to the function type. This restricts all the things that `a` can be to only be things that have order (otherwise how can we find a minimum). Secondly `Num a` forces `a` to be a number, this is necessary because you specified that the case for the empty list should be 0.

I'll explain 2 other ways to write the findMin function, trying to make them more concise than your definition (one of the benefits of Haskell is how concise it can be and I also find it helps when learning to see the multiple possibilities). The first will be using recursion and guards the second will be using a list comprehension.

We can't do much with `findMin [] = 0` so we'll move onto the lists with stuff in them.

We need to be careful with a recursive definition because eventually we will evaluate `findMin []` and always get 0 so we need to stop the recursion before that by defining a case for a single value:
`findMin [x] = x`

When passing a list as an argument to a function you can separate out its elements and give them each a name so `(x:xs)` means a value `x` is the first element followed by a list of elements `xs`.

For this definition we will define the first two elements on their own followed by the rest of the elements:

```
findMin (x:y:xs)
    | x < y = findMin (x:xs)
    | otherwise = findMin (y:xs)
```

The guards allow us to have multiple definitions for the function depending on a condition. If `x < y` we want to get rid of y as it cannot be the minimum so we find the minimum of `x` and the remaining elements, `xs`. If `x` is not smaller than `y` then the minimum value is either `y` or one of the values in `xs`.

The second way to define this function is using a list comprehension (this is my favourite as it is particularly concise).

We aren't using recursion so we don't need the case for one element we can keep our definition for an empty list and go straight to any list with elements:

`findMin xs = head [x | x <- xs, all (>= x) xs]`

So what's going on here? `[x | x <- xs]` creates a list of `x` values where `x` is all the elements from `xs`. We then add a condition to say we only want those values if `all (>= x) xs` meaning if all elements of `xs` are greater than or equal to `xs`.

This results in a list of the minimum elements. This might have one element if the minimum occurs once or it may have several if it occurs multiple times. Either way they are all the same so we just take the first using `head`.

Hope this helps and hope you have fun learning Haskell. Feel free to ask if you have any questions :)

Comment: +1 for the effort, but please don't recommend that list-comprehension solution. It's not idiomatic – `head` is shunned because partial...though actually you could get around by keeping the original `-> [a]` signature and replacing it with `take 1` – and more importantly, it's horribly inefficient: you compare each element with _all_ other elements, i.e. this has _O_ (_n_ ²) complexity rather than _O_ (_n_).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I appreciate the feedback. Just in case you didn't notice, before the definition using `head` I mentioned keeping the case for the empty list therefore as far as I'm aware there is no possible way for head to fail here. Is it still bad to use it regardless?

Regarding the complexity, I realise it's bad but that wasn't really the point of the answer. I was more looking at the different ways you can think about the problem. If efficiency were relevant and this wasn't just about learning then there's no reason not to use the already existing `minimum` function.

Comment: Thank you James, this was very helpful in explaining some of the basics of Haskell. I appreciate the time you took to show that.

Comment: @Cheyanne You're welcome, as someone pointed out in the comments, the list comprehension definition isn't very efficient so shouldn't really be used. The definition with guards should be ok but the most efficient is probably the definition of the already existing `minimum` function which is defined using folds.

Answer (score 0):

In ghci this function seems to do your trick:

```
let findMin x = if length x > 1 then min (head x) (findMin (tail x)) else head x
```

I'm learning as I try to answer some questions here, so any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Um... I don't think SO answers are supposed to beg for feedback, but... here you go: **1.** don't use `length`. It's very expensive (needs to traverse the entire list). To check whether a list is empty, use [`null`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:null) instead. But even better is pattern-matching right in the clause for `findMin`, i.e. seperate `findMin [] = ...` and `findMin (x:xs) = ...` **2.** avoid using `if...then...else`. Even when the boolean check can't be replaced with pattern-matching, guards usually look nicer than `if`.

Comment: **3.** don't use `head` nor `tail`, these are partial functions (don't work on empty lists), i.e. it's very easy to make a mistake which will then lead to annoying runtime errors. This wouldn't be an issue if you had used pattern matching `findMin (x:xs) = ...`, because then the head/tail parts would simply not be in scope in the places where an empty list was matched. **4.** `findMin` is actually more efficient when implemented with [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), but this isn't that critical.